# Weird stroke applying to text on hover

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I've been having a weird css quirk happen and I can't seem to find the culprit. I have some li links displayed on top of a image based background and when I hover the links they change colors but all apply a white border around the type which looks horrible.

[image]

I added a normalize.css stylesheet to my project hoping it would kill any standard style applying it but that didn't seem to work. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here is my styles for my navigation

Nav CSS

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20;
    z-index: 2;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

Nav HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="delivery">Delivery Locations</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: First, please show your actual code. None of that CSS would work because of the lack of { and }. Second, please show your relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Provide a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's SASS, it's correct syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think to compile it before putting it up.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Did you include any external files? I cannot produce the same result with yours.

Comment: Yeah I tried to put it in jsfiddle too and can't seem to trigger the same results. My project is using angularjs and I'm injecting the styles into my local server when I view... I wonder if something is going on with that...

Comment: what browser are you using it? it is the same for other browsers? can you check with the inspector to see if other styles are applied? maybe a `text-shadow` property? Try to create a reproduceable demo before you ask questions

Comment: So I added all styles I have for my project which aren't very many. The only thing not included was the import of normalize.css.

Comment: I'm using chrome. The same thing happens in firefox but not in safari. Normalize.css is apply a outline of 0 but this problem persisted before I had put normailze.css in my project. I can't reproduce the problem in jsfiddle for what ever reason... I left a photo of all styles being computed on the hover and I can't seem to see anything to cause it.

Comment: @Jleibham come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106265/weird-stroke-applying-to-text-on-hover

Comment: P.S you have a `top` of value `20` without a unit. should be `20px` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, I found that the problem was simply... you had duplicate navbar!

Since the navbar has a `fixed` position, both of them would be at the same exact place. So when you hover a link in the front navbar, it becomes black.. BUT the same link at the back remains white, thus, creating a weird stroke.

Here is a demo that reproduces your problem:

```css
body { background:#111; }

nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20px; /* was missing a unit (px) */
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- stroke you say? -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>Delivery Locations</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- who's behind me? -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>Delivery Locations</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Solution:** just remove the duplicated navbar... simple mistake.

```css
body { background:#111; }

nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20px; /* was missing a unit (px) */
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>Delivery Locations</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/bf28e5g9/

---

Notice how the `<app-navbar>` appears twice in your code:

[image: duplicate navbar creates white stroke on hover]

Comment: Thanks so much Aziz, I had realized I was duplicating them yesterday when looking into another issue. I noticed the outline had disappeared later but hadn't known why. But now you have given me the explanation for why that was! Always hate it when I get tripped up over such silly mistakes.